# If dynamic values exist somewhere else then format those values

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking to find if non-consecutive dynamic values are found in another sheet B. If so, I want to format those values in Sheet A.

The problem with my code is that it is going through a range while the values I am looking for are not consecutive. So I'm not sure if a for loop is what should be used in this case.

```
      function homeBoxlianTasks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var todolistsheet = ss.getSheetByName("To-Do List") 
  var todolistliantaskvalues = todolistsheet.getRange("B6:B").getValues();  
  var todolistlianbackground = todolistsheet.getRange("B6:B").getBackgrounds()   
  var homeboxsheet = ss.getSheetByName("HomeBox");
  var homeboxtaskvalues = homeboxsheet.getRange("homeboxtodotasks").getValues();  
  var backgrounds = [];
  var fontLines = [];     
  //for each row that data is present
  for(var i = 0; i < homeboxtaskvalues.length; i++) {
    var ltValue = todolistliantaskvalues[i][0];    
    var hValue = homeboxtaskvalues[i][0];
    var lbValue = todolistlianbackground[i][0];
    
      if((hValue === ltValue) && lbValue === '#d9ead3') {
      backgrounds.push(["#d9ead3"]); 
      fontLines.push(['line-through']);  
      }
   

    else {
      backgrounds.push([null]); 
      fontLines.push([null]);      
    } 
  }

  homeboxsheet.getRange("homeboxtodotask1").setFontLines(fontLines).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work for me.  But I'm not clear on what your question is.

Comment: Can you share a copy/sample of your spreadsheet and also please clarify the desired output. Remove sensitive data if any.

Comment: @Logan Hello and thank you for your kind assistance. I have 2 employees with a to-do list one under the other. Every time a task is done, there is a checkbox which will highlight and scratch the task in SheetA. I want that task to be also highlighted and scratched in Sheet B. Heres's a sample of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aA_q-jdeKBfCUiJX_p3HTKty-kEFbOo1DD7_rID9Q60/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your reply:

> I have 2 employees with a to-do list one under the other. Every time a task is done, there is a checkbox which will highlight and scratch the task in SheetA. I want that task to be also highlighted and scratched in Sheet B.

Try using an onEdit() trigger. Try the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var summarySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var range = e.range
  var row = range.getRow()
  var col = range.getColumn()

  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet0" && col == 1) {
    var taskCell = sheet.getRange(row, col + 1)
    var taskName = taskCell.getValue();

    if (range.isChecked()) {
      taskCell.setFontLine("line-through");
    } else {
      taskCell.setFontLine(null);
    }

    var checker = range.isChecked();
    while (checker != null) {
      row = row - 1
      checker = sheet.getRange(row, col).isChecked();
    }

    var name = sheet.getRange(row - 1, col + 1).getValue();

    var sumSheetRow = summarySheet.createTextFinder(name).findNext().getRow();
    var sumSheetLastCol = summarySheet.getLastColumn();
    var sumSheetCol = summarySheet.getRange(sumSheetRow,2,1,sumSheetLastCol-1).createTextFinder(taskName).findNext().getColumn();
    var sumSheetTaskCell = summarySheet.getRange(sumSheetRow, sumSheetCol);
    if (range.isChecked()) {
      sumSheetTaskCell.setFontLine("line-through");
    } else {
      sumSheetTaskCell.setFontLine(null);
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

This also removes the strikethrough if unchecked:
[image]

Hope this helps!

### EDIT:

**Try:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function test() {
  loopThroughTasks("Gaelle")
  loopThroughTasks("Lian")
}

function loopThroughTasks(name) {
  //ADD THE NAME AND RANGE IF NEEDED
  if (name == "Gaelle") {
    //Fixed Range and Start Row for Gaelle
    var tasks = sh0.getRange("A6:B21").getValues();
    var row = 6
  } else if (name == "Lian") {
    //Fixed Range and Start Row for Lian
    var tasks = sh0.getRange("A24:B33").getValues();
    var row = 24
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i][0] === 'Y') {
      var sh1Cell = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks[i][1]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh0.getRange(row, 2).setBackground('#d9ead3')
        .setFontLine('line-through');
      sh1.getRange(sh1Cell).setBackground('#d9ead3')
        .setFontLine('line-through');
    } else if (tasks[i][0] === 'N' && tasks[i][1] != "") {
      var sh1Cell = sh1.createTextFinder(tasks[i][1]).findNext().getCell(1, 1).getA1Notation()
      sh0.getRange(row, 2).setBackground('#fff2cc')
        .setFontLine(null);
      sh1.getRange(sh1Cell).setBackground('#fff2cc')
        .setFontLine(null);
    };
    row++
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is exactly what I wanted but is it possible to make it as a function instead of a trigger ? I want to assign that action to a button. I have many sheets and having this behavior as a trigger will cause many lags.

Comment: Hello Again Logan. I'm not sure why but the script is only finding "Hello 1" and "Hello 2". If I add more tasks. It does not find them. Here's the updated sheet for your reference:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aA_q-jdeKBfCUiJX_p3HTKty-kEFbOo1DD7_rID9Q60/edit#gid=842890630

Comment: Is the range of your sheets fixed? Lets say for example for Gaelle its the range A4:E21 @Karim

Comment: Hello Logan, no the range is not fixed because tasks may vary from one day to the other. But if it is easier to fix it for this code, then there's no problem in fixing it.

Comment: Ah got it. Can you also share your updated script

Comment: Hey Logan, I didn't update the script. I am using the one you provided. But it is not highlighting more than 2 tasks. Could you please have a look at it ? Also would it be possible to have it as a function instead of a trigger ? I have many sheets in my original spreadsheet and I'm worried it would cause lag on my sheet. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: From your reply "I'm not sure why but the script is only finding "Hello 1" and "Hello 2". If I add more tasks. It does not find them." . Are you currently using the script on the post? @Karim I'm thinking of an alternative which don't need trigger however I can only think of it as the range being fixed.

Comment: Yes I am currently using it on the spreadsheet that I provided. And no problem we can keep the ranges fixed if that solves it. Thank you so much

Comment: I have updated my answer, see the final part. Not the most efficient code but let me know if this works. @Karim

Comment: Hey @Logan I'm very sorry for my late reply, been on holidays and came back to work with an overload of tasks to finish. The script is awesome. Made some modifications to fit my needs. But exactly what I was looking for. A million thanks for this. I really appreciate your kind effort and support!

Comment: Hey @Logan I hope you are doing well! Maybe you can help out with this please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675577/nested-forloop-not-properly-iterating-charts

Comment: HI @Karim Glad to see that your concern is resolved. :)

Comment: Hey @Logan I hope you are doing well! I have a question concerning that same script you provided and I asked a new question about it. Could you please have a look at it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962119/apps-script-if-a-condition-is-met-on-sheets-a-b-c-apply-an-action-on-sheets

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially your code:

```
function myfunk() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange("B6:B" + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var bg1 = sh1.getRange("B6:B" + sh1.getLastRow()).getBackgrounds()
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vs2 = sh2.getRange("B6:B" + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var backgrounds = [];
  var fontLines = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vs2.length; i++) {
    if ((vs2[i][0] === vs1[i][0]) && bg1[i][0] === '#ffffff') {
      backgrounds.push(["#ffff00"]);
      fontLines.push(['line-through']);
    } else {
      backgrounds.push([null]);
      fontLines.push([null]);
    }
  }
  sh2.getRange(6,2,fontLines.length,1).setFontLines(fontLines).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
  sh1.getRange(6,2,fontLines.length,1).setFontLines(fontLines).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

Both sheet contain the same data

Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 10 | 9 | 3 | 10 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 10 | 7 |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 9 | 1 | 8 | 8 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 10 |
| 0 | 6 | 10 | 8 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 7 |
| 9 | 7 | 0 | 9 | 5 | 8 | 6 | 3 | 10 | 5 |
| 8 | 7 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 7 | 7 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 9 | 4 | 9 | 7 | 2 | 7 | 0 |
| 0 | 4 | 8 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

Image of highlight output:

[image]

Non consecutive values can be found it's simply a line by line search.  If it finds to elements in column B that are identical it highlight and strikes through.

Comment: Hello and thank you again for your kind assistance. Unfortunately it is still not working. Here's the spreadsheet for your reference and inside you have the HomeBoxTasks function where the problem lies https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aA_q-jdeKBfCUiJX_p3HTKty-kEFbOo1DD7_rID9Q60/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have 2 employees with a to-do list one under the other. Every time a task is done, there is a checkbox which will highlight and scratch the task in SheetA. I want that task to be also highlighted and scratched in Sheet B.

Comment: It works for me.  Perhaps you can  supply more information in your question to assist me in providing you with a better answer.

Comment: Hello Cooper. Thank you for your response. In the spreadsheet I shared,  in the "HomeBox" sheet only Hello 1 is highlighted and not Hello 2. Is it doing the same from your side ? This is where the problem lies (here is the spreadsheet FYR: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aA_q-jdeKBfCUiJX_p3HTKty-kEFbOo1DD7_rID9Q60/edit#gid=842890630)